# how to send email to multiple users one by one without BCC and CC using php

Tags: php, email, html-email

I want to send emails to multiple user, whom i have 4 emails and each of 4 emails are different from others. i simply want that i can send one email to all of them without BCC and CC stuff so email will send to them as ONE BY ONE.
here is my code:

```
$_SESSION['eventAdminEmail'] = array('mohsin@test.com, mohsin@test.com, mohsin@test.com, mohsin@test.com');

$toAdmin = $_SESSION['eventAdminEmail'];

$adminSubject = "hello";

$Mail_headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL; 
$Mail_headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".PHP_EOL;
$Mail_headers .= "From: test Support <test@test.org>".PHP_EOL;

if(isset($_SESSION['eventAdminEmail'])){ 
mail(explode(', ', $toAdmin), $adminSubject, $adminMessage, $Mail_headers); 
}
```

Comment: if one email is a@test.com so email send to him, then next user, and then next. i dont want that all of emails see who is receiving email. please.

Comment: have you check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use loop for it

```
$_SESSION['eventAdminEmail'] = array('mohsin@test.com, mohsin@test.com, mohsin@test.com, mohsin@test.com');



$adminSubject = "hello";

$Mail_headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL; 
$Mail_headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".PHP_EOL;
$Mail_headers .= "From: test Support <test@test.org>".PHP_EOL;

    if(isset($_SESSION['eventAdminEmail']))
    { 
       $toAdmin = $_SESSION['eventAdminEmail'];
      $arr_emails = explode(', ', $toAdmin[0]);
      foreach($arr_emails as $email)
      {
         mail($email, $adminSubject, $adminMessage, $Mail_headers); 
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it shoud be work

```
$eventAdminEmail = $_SESSION['eventAdminEmail'];
$arr_eventAdminEmail = array(); 
$arr_eventAdminEmail = explode(",", $eventAdminEmail[0]);

foreach($arr_eventAdminEmail as $key=>$email_id)
{
    mail($email_id,$adminSubject, $adminMessage, $Mail_headers); 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use this way

```
      $toAddres=explode(', ', $_SESSION['eventAdminEmail'][0]);

        if(isset($_SESSION['eventAdminEmail'])){ 
           foreach($toAddres as $toMail){
             mail($toMail, $adminSubject, $adminMessage, $Mail_headers); 
          }
        }
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['eventAdminEmail']` is array so need index 0